# Undefined e.values on google email notifications

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am using script editor in google spreadsheets to send an auto response email. However, I received Summary of failures notifications suggesting an invalid email: undefined (on the Mail.App line). I don't know how this error came about. Please help. Thanks so much.

```js
 function myFunction(e) {
   var Nickname = e.values [2];
   var email = e.values [10];
   var subject = "Form Submitted"
   var message =    

   "Thank you, " = + Nickname + ". Your response is accepted. You may want to check our     website @ iydsphilippines.weebly.com for registration payment details. Thanks and we hope to see you soon!";


  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
  }
```

[Here is a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RrQyBDgS0wYaH4FahScJmZNlkcLSo69HQn_H-W3byV4/edit?usp=sharing) to a copy of my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<>

I'm no expert however I also had the same issue and by trial and error I have discovered what the problem is.

It seems that recently Google have "upgraded / changed" the way fields are evaluated.

If any fields are blank then problems arise and as your email field in column K (i.e. the 10th field counting the first as zero) and some of the others are blank it seems to get confused. Until Google fix this "undocumented feature" I have a workaround.

Move your Email column to nearer the beginning i.e. straight after the name for example but before any optional fields, then renumber it in the code and you should be OK.

Specifically in your example: Move Column K to be Column C and renumber "var email = e.values [10]" to be "var email = e.values [2]" That should do it.

Good Luck and let me know how you get on. From Lester in the UK

Comment: A general workaround for this problem is [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938213/e-values-in-google-forms-skips-empty-answers-is-there-a-workaround).