# google form script not triggering

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I am trying to create a workflow in google forms. Its a simple leave application form that employees submit to get approval from their managers, HR, and finally management.

The form results feed into the google sheets as intended. i have written the following script in the form and later also in the sheet and set a trigger "on form submit". It worked fine last night and was able to sent the email confirmation i programmed into the script. For whatever reason it decided not to work today. Can someone tell me what they think went wrong? also is it best to create the script in the form or in the spreadsheet. My feeling is that in the spreadsheet might be better but i could be wrong. When the script did run last night, i am not sure which one worked (the one in the sheet or the one in the form). i only got one email for each test submission i made. here is the code:

```js
function leaveProcessInput(e) {

  var username = e.values [1];
  var name = e.values [2];
  var department = e.values [3];
  var leaveType = e.values [4];
  var fromDate = e.values [5];
  var toDate = e.values [6];
  var reason = e.values [7];
  var releiver = e.values [8];
  var contactAway = e.values [9];
  var subject = "Your " + leaveType + "Application Form has been submitted";
  var message = "Dear " + name + ", your " + leaveType + "from " + fromDate + "to " + toDate + "Application Form has been submitted at " + timestamp + ". You will be notified of its status once we have processed it. Regards, Finance & Admin team.";

   MailApp.sendEmail(username, subject, message);

}
```

I would really appreciate help on the above.

Comment: I'd suggest you set the trigger notification to "immediately"so that you can see what happens. This parameter is available in the same resource / trigger menu where you set the trigger.

Comment: You're indexing into `e.values` expecting that there will be items `0..9`. However, if any of the questions are not answered, the array will skip them. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938213/e-values-in-google-forms-skips-empty-answers-is-there-a-workaround/26975968#26975968) for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

this script (triggered on form submission) should be bound to the spreadsheet, not in the form.
I hope that solves it.

Try removing the spacing between 'e.values' and the [].
e.g. e.values [1] should be e.values[1]

The script should not be attached to the form, but only to the spreadsheet.

Comment: I have the script in both the spreadsheet and the form still it doesnt seem to trigger. Do you see anything wrong with the code?

Comment: The spacing is irrelevant; `values [1]` is the same as `values[1]`, or `values   [         1        ]` for that matter.

Comment: Thanks guys, it works now!  I setup the notification as Serge suggested and I found out that line 14 refers to timeStamp which I have not defined as e.values[0]. So I removed it and th script works perfectly. However when I tried to define as follows: var timeStamp = e.values [0] it didn't work. In any case I removed it and it now work! Thanks agai