# How to collect data from form entries when editing a previously submitted form using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google form that allows users to edit a previously submitted response. When a form is submitted the first time, I capture the timestamp, serial # and tech as variables and push them to a slack channel as a chat notification along with writing all of the responses to a spreadsheet. I am using an onFormSubmit trigger for the function. This part works great.

There are fields that are not required, but are filled out later by editing the form responses. When the form is edited and submitted, the serial # and tech fields are not changed. The spreadsheet is updated accordingly, but for the slack channel notification, the only variable that has data is the timestamp. The serial and tech are blank due to those fields not changing on the form. How do I create a variable for serial and tech using the pre-existing form response for my slack notification?

My current code checks if the tech value is blank or not and if not blank it sends a slack notification. If it is blank, it does nothing. If it is blank, I want it to capture the existing form responses as an array that I can use the values to create a slack notification showing the same data, but include that the original form has been re-submitted with the pre-existing values.

I am new to coding and have been researching and testing for over a week with no results.

```
var timestamp = 'Timestamp'                         //type exact column header as shown in workbook
var tech = 'Troubleshooting Tech'                   //type exact column header as shown in workbook
var parts = 'Part(s)#  Ordered'                     //type exact column header as shown in workbook
var serial = 'Serial #'                             //type exact column header as shown in workbook
var slackWebHook = ''    //Paste Slack webhook here
function SendSlackMessageEvent(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let data = e.namedValues
  let payload = buildAlert(data);

      if (data[tech] == '') {

    }
  if (data[tech] != '') {
  sendAlert(payload);
}
}

function buildAlert(data) {
  let timestampe = data[timestamp];
  let teche = data[tech];
  let seriale = data[serial];
  let partse = data[parts];

  let payload = {
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": ":bell: *Breakfix Ticket Submitted* :bell:"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "divider"
      },
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": teche + " submitted a ticket on " + timestampe
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": "Serial #: " + seriale
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": "Parts Needed: " + partse
        }
      }
    ]
  };
  return payload;
}

function sendAlert(payload) {
 // const webhook = ""; //Paste your webhook URL here
  const webhook = slackWebHook; //slack webhook URL
  var options = {
    "method": "post", 
    "contentType": "application/json", 
    "muteHttpExceptions": true, 
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload) 
  };
  
  try {
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(webhook, options);
  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Is your code complete( `tech` isnot declared)?

Comment: I added the declarations to the code. Instead of using and index like data[1] for timestamp, I'm using the headers from the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are assuming that an unchanged response will be included in the `namedValues` properties as an empty string but it will not be included so:

`data[tech]` will return `undefined`

Instead of

```
 if (data[tech] == '') {

    }
  if (data[tech] != '') {
  sendAlert(payload);
}
```

you might use

```
if(data[tech]){
  // add here what should be done when data[tech] has a value

} else {
  // add here what should be done when data[tech] is undefined

}
```

By the other hand, since the form submit event object includes a range property having the response corresponding range you could use it instead of namedValues property:

`e.range.getValues()` return Array holding a Array with the values logged in the spreadsheet.

Related

- [e.values in google forms skips empty answers, is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25938213/1595451)

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit

Comment: ``if (data[tech] == '')`` does return true and not as undefined. When it returns as nothing, I want it to pull the data from the spreadsheet for that form response, but I can not figure out how to do that. I have tried ``e.range.getValues()`` but the logger shows ``[FormResponse, FormResponse, FormResponse, FormResponse, FormResponse, FormResponse, FormResponse, FormResponse]``.